# How to stop data from repeating for data being called from multiple tables sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to print out the following columns `isbn`, `title`, `fName`, `surname`, and `quantity`, but since there are multiple orders the data prints out for each order instead of just having a number for the amount of orders. How do I do this?

[image]

```
SELECT book.isbn, book.title, author.fName, author.surname, orders.quantity
FROM book, author, orders
WHERE orders.bookID = book.isbn
ORDER BY book.isbn DESC;
```

Comment: Can you show your data structure with a sample of the table please? It sounds like you need to look at GROUP BY but I can't say without more information

Comment: What do you want (result) ? What have you got in your tables (schema) ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using JOINS instead of FROM from several tables? As it stands, there is no connection between book and author in your select, and that could lead to a lot of duplication.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/esZgUMN.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause. I'd also suggest adding explicit joins (and removing the now superfluous `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT book.isbn, book.title, author.fName, author.surname, SUM(orders.quantity) AS TotalOrders
FROM (book INNER JOIN author ON book.authorID = author.authorID)
  INNER JOIN orders ON book.isbn = orders.bookID
GROUP BY book.isbn, book.title, author.fName, author.surname
ORDER BY book.isbn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the quantity of each individual order, your query is going to return a row for each order.  If you are using some sort of application to display the results, then you can use application code to solve the problem.

On the other hand, if you just want to know how many books have been ordered, then your query becomes:

```
SELECT book.isbn, book.title, author.fName, author.surname, sum(orders.quantity) total
FROM book, author, orders
WHERE orders.bookID = book.isbn\
group by book.isbn, book.title, author.fName, author.surname
ORDER BY book.isbn DESC
```